# FFmpeg drawtext support for Hindi fonts

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext, hindi, kerning

We are trying to use FFmpeg drawtext to support Hindi fonts. But the ordering of the data is not correct.

The unicode for Hindi text is passed like this

```
1. पिता माता िस्रफ
```

But output renders as

[image]

Have used the following code for generating the output

```
ffmpeg  -framerate 30 -t 10 -i /opt/test.png drawtext=text_shaping=1:fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:fontfile=/usr/share/xx.ttf:text='1. पिता माता िस्रफ':y='max(550,700-t*200)':x=40,format=yuv420p[v] /usr/share/nginx/html/hello_v.mp4
```

Had done `harfbuzz support` and `--libfribidi` is also enabled.

The problem is the text gets drawn from left to right. Also found there is a `use_kerning` flag in drawtext, will that help, if yes how to use it.

Comment: Description isn't accurate. Text is not being drawn left to right. If it was, `प` would be at the right-end. This is a ligature rendering problem and Harfbuzz doesn't have support yet, AFAIK. You'll need a font with glyphs readymade i.e. `पि` is one character.