# Can't render or join Hindi ligatures in FFmpeg drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been trying to drawtext over a video in Hindi language but some characters are not rendering properly:

[image: output]

The proper way is:

[image: should be]

I have enabled `libfridi`, `libfontconfig` and `libfreetype`.

Even tried on Ubuntu.

ANS: please see comment to Pops answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48298061/5726027

Comment: I did, but the solution to the problem is not there. I think it's an harfbuzz issue but it's already installed on my machine. maybe it's not been used while rendering text in ffmpeg

Comment: @Gyan is there been any development in 6 years regarding this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Convert the Unicode to KrutiDev and use the KrutiDev font. I have done an example using C# [for Unity here](https://github.com/abusaadp/Unity3dHindiRenderer).

Comment: yeah, that's the way to go but that adds one more step to flow. so what I did was convert text to pango transparent image as pango support ligature joining. then I used those images as overlay to ffmpeg export.